# How to use JacksonConverter to convert Json object with a variable that changes

Tags: json, jackson

Let's say I have this `JSON`

```
{
    "anonymous": {
        "id": 39053697,
        "name": "Anonymous"
    }
}
```

The `anonymous` is the query sent into the API and will change for each query-by-name. So if I were to make a query for `John` it would look like this:

```
{
    "john": {
        "id": 3456987,
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

I am trying to use JacksonConverter to convert this Json to an object in Android.
Currently I have:

```
public class NameVo {
    public InfoVo john;

    public InfoVo getResults() {
        return john;
    }
}
```

This is how I currently match the `JSON` to an `Object` and I am unsure on how to make my `NameVo` flexible for all of the possible queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@JsonAnySetter` annotation:

```
class NameVo {

    public InfoVo value;

    public InfoVo getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAnyValue(String propertyName, InfoVo value) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + propertyName);
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

Now, simple usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println("Serialize to JSON:");
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, NameVo.class));
```

Above program prints:

```
Serialize to JSON:
Name: john
InfoVo [id=39053697, name=Anonymous]
```